# Magento - Integrity Constraint Violation - Tier pricing

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a 3rd party extension for magento which dynamically alters the price of a product based on its weight, precious metal price & a forex feed, which all works perfectly fine. I dont **think** this is related but i think its worth mentioning just incase

The problem comes when i try to save tier pricing into any of the products i get the error -

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '49-1-0-5.0000-0' for key 'E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087'
```

saving the same product without tier pricing is fine.

NOTE - the 3rd party extension doesnt affect the tier price only the main price.

I have a product which already had tier pricing and now that product or even the category page which contains that product cant be viewed it gives the following error -

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '18-1-0-5.0000-0' for key 'E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087'

Trace:
#0 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[23000]...')
#1 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[23000]...')
#2 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1648): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array)
#3 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php(195): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#4 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1124): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#5 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/local/Siju/Bullionprice/Model/Observer.php(104): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save()
#6 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Siju_Bullionprice_Model_Observer->updatePriceFrontend(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Siju_Bullionprice_Model_Observer), 'updatePriceFron...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#9 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(267): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#10 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(592): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterLoad()
#11 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(226): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterLoad()
#12 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/local/Siju/Bullionprice/Model/Observer.php(113): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load()
#13 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Siju_Bullionprice_Model_Observer->updatePriceOnListingFrontend(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Siju_Bullionprice_Model_Observer), 'updatePriceOnLi...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#16 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(526): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#17 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(885): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->_afterLoad()
#18 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Observer.php(78): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#19 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Review_Model_Observer->catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#20 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1311): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Review_Model_Observer), 'catalogBlockPro...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#21 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#22 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(163): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_p...', Array)
#23 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#24 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#26 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(85): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#27 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(70): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#28 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/thebulli/...')
#29 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#30 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#31 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#32 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#34 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#36 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#37 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/thebulli/...')
#38 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#39 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#40 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#41 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#42 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#43 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#44 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#45 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#46 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#47 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#48 /home/thebulli/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#49 /home/thebulli/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#50 {main}
```

Ive read elsewhere people have fixed similar duplicate entry issues by altering certain database tables directly, however it seems to be specific to the error code and i cant find any reference to E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087 in the database.

I can fix the issue by deleting tier prices from catalog_product_entity_tier but this doesnt fix the issue of being unable to save the prices back.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Ben I have your same issue. Have you solved it in any way? thanks

Comment: Hi Michelangelo, i'm afraid the 3rd party werent interested in solving the problem so my only way forward was to drop the plugin & write my own.